# Soft restart method with Python

Tags: python, selenium, session

My code below will open a website and scrape values into an array and plot. Notice at the bottom, One can comment out "driver.quit()" and when the Python code stops, the webpage of interest is still open. At a short time later, I would like to soft start the Python code and continue reading from the website. My attempt was to print out the value for the driver and skip to this value without having to open a new page. Once I am on the welcome page it takes a lot of time/effort to get to the desired page and I would like to avoid that. Look at the third line of code where I have pasted the value of the driver for the session that is currently open. Python does not like that. Is there a way to continue on that session while it is open in Python?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://my_example.com/welcome")
#driver = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="1a636e51f3d40bd9b66996e3d52d945b")>

my_name = ["nm25", "nm26", "nm27", "nm33", "nm38", "nm41", "nm45", ]
data_points = 450
my_file = np.zeros((13, 7, data_points))
x = []
y = []

soup = "chicken" # Initialization constant
while soup.find(my_name[0]) == -1:
    source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    soup = (soup.get_text())
    time.sleep(5) 
    tim = time.time()
    my_cntr =0

plt.title("Title") 
plt.xlabel(" Time") 
plt.ylabel("y axis amplitude") 

for i in range(data_points):
    source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml") # was "html.parser"
    soup3 = (soup.get_text())
    soup2 = (soup.get_text("**", strip=True)) # adds "**" between values for ease of reading
    x_pos = soup2.find(my_name[0])  # Remove all but First name
    soup2 = soup2[x_pos-2:] # Data starts with "**"
        
    for j in range(len(my_name)): # Go through all of the  names
        for k in range(0, 13): # The number of values to read per name
            soup2 = soup2[2:] # Remove **
            x_pos = soup2.find('**')
            if k < 2 or k==6:
                my_file[k, j, i] =time.time() - tim # adds time stamp
            else:
                my_file[k, j, i] = soup2[:x_pos]
                
            soup2 = soup2[x_pos:]
                
            if ( k== 7) and j==0 :
                x.append(my_file[0,0,i] )
                y.append(my_file[7,0,i] )
                my_cntr = my_cntr +1
                if my_cntr/20 == int(my_cntr/20):
                    plt.plot(x, y)
                    plt.pause(0.2)
            plt.show()    
    
driver.quit()  # remove this line to leave the browser open
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the session id and setting the value. You should probably save the session id in a config.py file, json file, txt file, etc. and access it later

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://my_example.com/welcome")
# do stuff and then save the session id at the end
session_id = driver.session_id

import json
# save the session id in a json file
with open("sample.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps({'session_id': session_id}))
```

Once the code finishes running and the selenium browser is still open, you should be able to have another .py file that you will run to get the session id you just saved in a json file so you can access the open browser again

```
import json

# open the json file
with open('sample.json', 'r') as f:
    session_id = json.load(f)['session_id']

driver.session_id = sessioin_id
# do more stuff
```

Comment: I am a novice. What do I use for driver? It is now undefined.